# Showing a list of emails client before sending emails

Tags: android, xamarin.android, email-client

i used this code to send email in my monodroid application:

```
try {
                Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ActionSend);
                i.SetType ("message/rfc822");
                i.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[]{TxtEmail .Text });
                i.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraSubject, "My Subject");
                i.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraText, "");
                try {
                    StartActivity (Intent .CreateChooser (i, "Sending Email"));
                } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                    Toast .MakeText (this, "There are no mail client available", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Common .HandleException (ex);
            }
```

i expect that this code show a list of all email clients and user select which that want and then go to the email client and user send the email.
But when i fire this code it directly goes to the Gmail app of device(While i have another email clients like android default mail client) and not show other email clients to user select which want. How can I do it?
Maybe user wants to select another email client.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an account set up in these other mail clients? The AOSP Mail app (presumably what you consider "android default mail client" to be) does not enable its `ACTION_SEND` activity if there are no registered email accounts in the app.

Comment: I have not an account setup on AOSP Mail app but in other application that wants to send any emails a list comes and recommend me gmail and this mail app. why this code do not do this?